# AIC and BIC come out as NA when running CFA in R

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor

Does anyone have ideas why when running a CFA in R I'm getting most of my fit statistics to calculate, but AIC and BIC are both NA?

I load lavaan, SEMplot, SEMtools, and haven; load the file (have tried as .sav and as .csv); define the models; then run the analysis. Here's a sample:

```
Model1Fit <- cfa(model=Model1, data = dataset, orthogonal = FALSE, test = "Satorra-Bentler", std.lv = TRUE)
summary(Model1Fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
semPaths(Model1Fit)
```

It also seems to happen without the Satorra-Bentler correction. Everything gets run correctly except this section of output:

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

Loglikelihood user model ($H_0$)                    **NA**

Loglikelihood unrestricted model ($H_1$)           **NA**

Number of free parameters                        **27**

Akaike (AIC)                                     **NA**

Bayesian (BIC)                                   **NA**

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I had previously tried changing all of my variables in my SPSS file to "scaled," but what worked was doing that AND deleting the level labels (1=agree, etc) from each variable. Using varTable(dataset) let me see that my variables were still called "labelled" rather than "numeric" until I deleted those level labels.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show us your model1 specifications? As well as perhaps a head() call of your dataframe and a bit of that output? This will help us assist you.

Lavaan needs to derive a null model from your specification to get fit statistics from.

Sorry, I know I'm not supposed to ask for more information or clarification in an answer, but I don't have enough rep to post a comment yet!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and sorry I didn't get back to you with the additional info! I figured it out-- posted as answer if you're interested.